# Replace text only when occuring between specific characters

Tags: javascript, string

I have a **string** like this:

```
- - This is the place where the people like to join think-tanks and have fun.
```

I can obviously replace all hyphens with a space using either:

```
my_string.replace(/-/g, ' ')

my_string.split('-').join(' ')
```

I need to replace only the hyphen in think-tank with a space. The other hyphens can be left alone.

How can I **target only the hyphen between letters within a string**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capture the letters using `\w`, and then replace the dash with a space"

```
str.replace(/(\w)\-(\w)/gi, '$1 $2')
```

The word metacharacter is a shorthand for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, i.e. including digits, upper/lowercase alphabets and underscore.

```js
const str = '- - This is the place where the people like to join think-tanks and have fun.';

console.log(str.replace(/(\w)\-(\w)/gi, '$1 $2'));
```